# Unable to set up word wrap in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, word-wrap

I'm getting this error when trying to enable word wrap:

```
Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing bracket in Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:3:13
```

This is the code in my Preferences.sublime-settings:

```
{
"ignored_packages":
"word_wrap": "true",

[
    "Vintage"
]
}
```

Comment: try removing the quotes around `"true"` and make it just `"word_wrap": true`. Also, looks like the ordering is mixed up in your commands there... see my answer below (comments won't let me format code nicely)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage"
],
"word_wrap": true
}
```

I changed two things:

1. Place `"Vintage"` inside the list of ignored packages.
2. Removed the quotes around `"true"`in `"word_wrap": "true"`.

Answer (score 34):

You can also set it manually, without code just go to `Sublime Text` check the menus, click on view menu and in there click on the word wrap.

For more check the image below.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean go into "tabs"? I found it in view.

Comment: I added an image to answer check that

Comment: Yeah, but you have to do this each time. This is only a temporary solution (and thus it's mostly not a solution, but an annoyance).

Comment: @Nik-Lz I set it at the time when I installed and its working perfect since then. I do not have to do it each time. its almost a year back when I set it.

Answer (score 7):

All the above solutions(Default and User Settings) can be overridden by syntax-specific settings. 
Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific

These are specific to file type that you are currently using. eg. *Perl.sublime-settings*.
Add this to the file:

```
{
    "word_wrap": true
}
```